# Onde fica localizado Docker Store no Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Eu estou estudando docker, logo essa pergunta que estou fazendo é de debutante.

1. Imagens são os arquivos que contêm as configuração da máquina que se quer criar.
2. Container é uma instância dessa image rodando e funcionando.
3. Docker Store é o registro das imagens docker. Seria o "Local" onde se armazena as diversas imagens que irão instanciar os containers docker.

Então, quando se quer rodar um container o docker vai dentro do Docker Store e procura pela imagem do container solicitado.

Instalei o docker na minha máquina ubuntu.
Eu consigo rodar o docker mas não sei de onde está vindo essa imagem.
Fiz o pull inicial da imagem hello-world. Foi feito o download mas eu não sei
fisicamente onde fica guardada essa imagem.

Então onde fica localizado fisicamente (path) do Docker Store por default?
Ou melhor, qual o comando docker para verificar onde é o Docker Store daquela instalação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro faça login (exemplo abaixo do meu contexto, ubuntu também):

```
$ sudo docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't 
have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one. 
Username (user): user
Username (user): Digite a senha
Login Succeeded
```

Após o login vc pode utilizar vários comandos, só não sei se vai te ajudar muito, a forma do docker construir os artefatos é bem complexa, por exemplo com o comando `docker info` vc vai descobrir que a raiz do do docker fica em `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker` (no meu contexto), a partir dai vc vai encontrar tudo, images, containers, etc. Em seguida, vc pode verificar a compelexidade do sistema com comando `tree /var/lib/docker`, para ser possível colar aqui eu limitei o tree à profundidade de 3, veja o resultado (parcial).

```
$ sudo tree -L 3  /var/lib/docker/ 
/var/lib/docker/
├── aufs
│   ├── diff
│   │   ├── 109fcc3eb0ea93d2576fc5ed6fa5ae33d4dbfb344061a6802feecd022a3bb84b
│   │   ├── 178191e9492b90a31a3d13c07c39d3ab41a557379347730d857c3bc3fc735e36
│   │   ├── 178191e9492b90a31a3d13c07c39d3ab41a557379347730d857c3bc3fc735e36-init
│   │   ├── 189e7299d5f883444b91c9d020d231c1d1add078fb1f34b2d04d27ff9a7e8327
│   │   ├── 1d717521113b760e648f76cf347484958d3f5457a47336f87abaad858e7ba564
│   │   ├── 306ef406016a1078f4e45d2094d5099989194d65d6455ce39617b01ec04b96d2
│   │   ├── 36292f12e0b0a98d279f3fc55c68c23e98d065a1f67ba1c5819c1a9b2a29f8ec
│   │   ├── 382d434dd6da0a10364f310033f2b8c627fa9fa23e414fc510345f191de1a932
│   │   ├── 583fae26ed74e736c0cc84fb4dc6181b4994e6da9bf6b05068b00f7fd8d9ff52
│   │   ├── 5e50cb22c4f8edeba6a35bf60f8b2cf17181ff94fbb7864082001b5612186edf
│   │   ├── 7021ba5bc40a5bb5485eb3595babda1b32f5f314462276eb36f26f68abd479d2
│   │   ├── 7148b8e7abb56ecfd219ede7c2fda5d97d295ae2b917be07777150552f76fd48
│   │   ├── 79c5b73accaebb7d34ee7b09e8308a4113e750020454553dc1d40405818fb044
│   │   ├── 7a9079a68382a3a059d2e3c304f6c7bf78cdfa711e1ee797a1069c0916702a32
│   │   ├── 8932ee3cfac5c28298dbc898fc6772d6e9c761853385abb57fd06b991039d01a
│   │   ├── 90deda4aa2cb1a8267e2827a430db2537c47188b6b455e6ff3b977f1583ee398
│   │   ├── 9536443410f3f4bb4bbaaf9a884c04f3d6a72fb4245e24150fa1b11a3a1af691
│   │   ├── ade74ca2ab4aeb242524125bf94b9bb733c749f3e1674f4aee39c96987e1f10e
│   │   ├── c984433fe781e3e178f8c7c43a643b335b01cf68536c9382afd6a16fe0acbc3a
│   │   ├── d13d50ed234e25bfbe91e04d26cf983a9aa77cd3b3f35b254a906b29695833b7
│   │   └── ec9443cd7a3f822a0fbfb0424f5e219f75749af8d917cbfb012daa2aeca599b8
│   ├── layers
│   │   ├── 109fcc3eb0ea93d2576fc5ed6fa5ae33d4dbfb344061a6802feecd022a3bb84b
│   │   ├── 178191e9492b90a31a3d13c07c39d3ab41a557379347730d857c3bc3fc735e36
│   │   ├── 178191e9492b90a31a3d13c07c39d3ab41a557379347730d857c3bc3fc735e36-init
│   │   ├── 189e7299d5f883444b91c9d020d231c1d1add078fb1f34b2d04d27ff9a7e8327
│   │   ├── 1d717521113b760e648f76cf347484958d3f5457a47336f87abaad858e7ba564
│   │   ├── 306ef406016a1078f4e45d2094d5099989194d65d6455ce39617b01ec04b96d2
│   │   ├── 36292f12e0b0a98d279f3fc55c68c23e98d065a1f67ba1c5819c1a9b2a29f8ec
│   │   ├── 382d434dd6da0a10364f310033f2b8c627fa9fa23e414fc510345f191de1a932
│   │   ├── 583fae26ed74e736c0cc84fb4dc6181b4994e6da9bf6b05068b00f7fd8d9ff52
│   │   ├── 5e50cb22c4f8edeba6a35bf60f8b2cf17181ff94fbb7864082001b5612186edf
│   │   ├── 7021ba5bc40a5bb5485eb3595babda1b32f5f314462276eb36f26f68abd479d2
│   │   ├── 7148b8e7abb56ecfd219ede7c2fda5d97d295ae2b917be07777150552f76fd48
│   │   ├── 79c5b73accaebb7d34ee7b09e8308a4113e750020454553dc1d40405818fb044
│   │   ├── 7a9079a68382a3a059d2e3c304f6c7bf78cdfa711e1ee797a1069c0916702a32
│   │   ├── 8932ee3cfac5c28298dbc898fc6772d6e9c761853385abb57fd06b991039d01a
│   │   ├── 90deda4aa2cb1a8267e2827a430db2537c47188b6b455e6ff3b977f1583ee398
│   │   ├── 9536443410f3f4bb4bbaaf9a884c04f3d6a72fb4245e24150fa1b11a3a1af691
│   │   ├── ade74ca2ab4aeb242524125bf94b9bb733c749f3e1674f4aee39c96987e1f10e
│   │   ├── c984433fe781e3e178f8c7c43a643b335b01cf68536c9382afd6a16fe0acbc3a
│   │   ├── d13d50ed234e25bfbe91e04d26cf983a9aa77cd3b3f35b254a906b29695833b7
│   │   └── ec9443cd7a3f822a0fbfb0424f5e219f75749af8d917cbfb012daa2aeca599b8
│   └── mnt
│       ├── 109fcc3eb0ea93d2576fc5ed6fa5ae33d4dbfb344061a6802feecd022a3bb84b
│       ├── 178191e9492b90a31a3d13c07c39d3ab41a557379347730d857c3bc3fc735e36
│       ├── 178191e9492b90a31a3d13c07c39d3ab41a557379347730d857c3bc3fc735e36-init
│       ├── 189e7299d5f883444b91c9d020d231c1d1add078fb1f34b2d04d27ff9a7e8327
│       ├── 1d717521113b760e648f76cf347484958d3f5457a47336f87abaad858e7ba564
│       ├── 306ef406016a1078f4e45d2094d5099989194d65d6455ce39617b01ec04b96d2
│       ├── 36292f12e0b0a98d279f3fc55c68c23e98d065a1f67ba1c5819c1a9b2a29f8ec
│       ├── 382d434dd6da0a10364f310033f2b8c627fa9fa23e414fc510345f191de1a932
│       ├── 583fae26ed74e736c0cc84fb4dc6181b4994e6da9bf6b05068b00f7fd8d9ff52
│       ├── 5e50cb22c4f8edeba6a35bf60f8b2cf17181ff94fbb7864082001b5612186edf
│       ├── 7021ba5bc40a5bb5485eb3595babda1b32f5f314462276eb36f26f68abd479d2
│       ├── 7148b8e7abb56ecfd219ede7c2fda5d97d295ae2b917be07777150552f76fd48
│       ├── 79c5b73accaebb7d34ee7b09e8308a4113e750020454553dc1d40405818fb044
│       ├── 7a9079a68382a3a059d2e3c304f6c7bf78cdfa711e1ee797a1069c0916702a32
│       ├── 8932ee3cfac5c28298dbc898fc6772d6e9c761853385abb57fd06b991039d01a
│       ├── 90deda4aa2cb1a8267e2827a430db2537c47188b6b455e6ff3b977f1583ee398
│       ├── 9536443410f3f4bb4bbaaf9a884c04f3d6a72fb4245e24150fa1b11a3a1af691
│       ├── ade74ca2ab4aeb242524125bf94b9bb733c749f3e1674f4aee39c96987e1f10e
│       ├── c984433fe781e3e178f8c7c43a643b335b01cf68536c9382afd6a16fe0acbc3a
│       ├── d13d50ed234e25bfbe91e04d26cf983a9aa77cd3b3f35b254a906b29695833b7
│       └── ec9443cd7a3f822a0fbfb0424f5e219f75749af8d917cbfb012daa2aeca599b8
├── containers
│   └── 3c12fb559cc5a4191ceee4e0e7fe8b173cf67cddd18f36735ed4c3efe542e729
│       ├── 3c12fb559cc5a4191ceee4e0e7fe8b173cf67cddd18f36735ed4c3efe542e729-json.log
│       ├── checkpoints
│       ├── config.v2.json
│       ├── hostconfig.json
│       ├── hostname
│       ├── hosts
│       ├── resolv.conf
│       ├── resolv.conf.hash
│       └── shm
├── image
│   └── aufs
│       ├── distribution
│       ├── imagedb
│       ├── layerdb
│       └── repositories.json
├── network
│   └── files
│       └── local-kv.db
├── plugins
│   ├── storage
│   │   └── blobs
│   └── tmp
├── swarm
├── tmp
├── trust
└── volumes
    └── metadata.db
```

Com o comando sudo `docker images`, vc pode descobrir que tem `n` imagens (2 no meu contexto), SQN, com o comando `docker images -a` vc pode descobrir que tem `n` vezes (8 no meu contexto) o que aparece sem o `-a`, é que, por default, o comando não lista as imagens "intermediárias".

```
$ sudo docker images 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
skype               latest              fdbb095b559c        3 months ago        584MB
debian              stable              58cf158c4bd6        3 months ago        123MB
```

### SQN

```
$ sudo docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
skype               latest              fdbb095b559c        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              e8d86bada138        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              b9ccc42ebb18        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              e0d5c965fbb2        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              e7a97b82e06a        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              886fcead9731        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              25842c5c01f2        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              85254cda0f92        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              08e9b7c1a0df        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              fe9d47a01aff        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              cbfe10f545a1        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              944c17b0bc54        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              bda07b9cf4ca        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              dbf4386143ec        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              c3cf8fa7450a        3 months ago        584MB
<none>              <none>              bd374470d432        3 months ago        449MB
<none>              <none>              c7d7c7ec8796        3 months ago        396MB
<none>              <none>              d64937d09002        3 months ago        376MB
<none>              <none>              1d5c66ae3575        3 months ago        320MB
<none>              <none>              78c0a643553e        3 months ago        143MB
<none>              <none>              791c39f99208        3 months ago        123MB
<none>              <none>              77d09a74fa9e        3 months ago        123MB
<none>              <none>              4e4fc161ac04        3 months ago        123MB
debian              stable              58cf158c4bd6        3 months ago        123MB
```

Digite  `$ docker --help` para ver a lista dos comandos.